# MySQL процедуры для чайников

Tags: php, mysql

Имею две таблицы с товарами интернет магазина. В одну попадают только товары от различных поставщиков с указанием ID поставщика. Во вторую попадают все цены и наличие по каждому товару первой таблице, по каждому складу поставщика.

Так как SQL недавно появился в моей жизни в таких масштабах, приходится просить помощи, не во всем сам могу разобраться.

Кратко о данных в таблицах:

Таблица с товарами выглядит вот так

[image: Товары]

Таблица с ценами так

[image: Цены]

Как видно на изображениях, на один товар может приходиться несколько различных цен на различных складах. 
Написал процедуру для усреднения цен по складам каждого поставщика.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `average`(IN `v_id` INT, IN `v_in_id` INT, IN `v_sup_id` INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE vPrice INT;
  DECLARE vAmount INT;

  SET vPrice = (SELECT (SUM(buy_price*amount)/SUM(amount)) FROM td_prices WHERE buy_price > 0 AND amount > 0 AND item_id = v_in_id and sup_id = v_sup_id);
  SET vAmount  = (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM td_prices WHERE item_id = v_in_id and sup_id = v_sup_id);

  UPDATE td_items SET buy_price = vPrice, amount = vAmount WHERE id = v_id;
END;;
```

Не могу сказать что хорошо написал, опыта не хватает, возможно и заглючит при нулевой цене или количестве, но пока работает.

Процедуру выполняю в PHP скрипте - делаю выборку всех id,in_id,sup_id из таблицы items и подставляю их в мою процедуру, вызывая ее в цикле перебора этой самой выборки.
Грубо говоря

```
$data = $sql->get('SELECT * FROM td_items');
foreach($data as $item) { $sql->query('call avarage(_ids_from_$item_here)'); }
```

Да, идея банальная и не самая производительная..

После выполнения процедуры таблица заполняется вполне корректно

[image: Result]

**Собственно, вопрос:** Сейчас на 10 тысяч имеющихся в таблице items записей выполнение всего моего скрипта занимает аж 10 минут (на ноутбуке). Это никуда не годится, я прекрасно понимаю что если объеденить foreach PHP и SQL в одной единой процедуре, процесс пойдет намного быстрее. Но опыта не хватает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, методы оптимизации всей этой "выборки". Второй день бьюсь с sql курсорами и переменными, результата и понимания 0

Comment: А зачем ID поставщика у вас во второй таблице. Судя по всему он у вас напрямую зависит от записи в первой таблице. Т.е. у вас во второй таблице по приведенному примеру не может быть таких записей: (in_id=3355, sup_id=3) И (in_id=3355, sup_id=4) - т.е. для in_id=3355 sup_id всегда равен 3. Если так - то во второй таблице это поле не нужно.

Comment: У нас парсятся прайс-листы, данные после парсинга попадают в разные таблицы - для каждого из поставщиков таблица своя. При парсинге цены автоматически попадают в таблицу с ценами, с указанием ID поставщика, ID записи из его таблицы и есть in_id в таблице items, в которую после обработки и чисти попадают все записи из всех таблиц после парсинга. Потом эти данные обрабатываются, и попадают. Есть 4 таблицы, потом они сливаются в одну. Но мы храним id по каждой записи как внутри таблицы items так и в ценах. in_id и item_id не являются уникальными для каждой из таблиц, они привязаны к sup_id.

Comment: Жесть то какая. В реляционных БД не стоит делать отдельные таблицы для каждого поставщика. Стоит хранить в одной таблице. Тогда ID будет один и работать будет гораздо проще потому как обработать информацию по всем поставщикам можно будет одним запросом. Вообще тут процедура даже не нужна. То же самое можно сделать без всяких циклов читающих таблицы и построчной обработки - тупо одним запросом update. И пересчет всех 10к записей точно не нужен. можно было бы в таблице прайса вести поле timestamp и пересчитывать только те товары по которым записи менялись.

Comment: Я с Вами полностью согласен. Просто в виду некоторых особенностей системы (интерфейса склада, в частности), мы должны иметь разные таблицы для разных поставщиков. Дело в том, что изначально все данные от поставщиков имеют различный формат, а парсятся прайс листы в формате XML. Одни поставщики указывают артикул, вторые нет. Кто-то указывает характеристики товара, кто-то нет. Вобщем в одной таблице может быть 10 столбцов, а во второй - 50. После обработки данные сливаются в одну таблицу, с нужным нам форматом.

Comment: После того как мы слили все в одну таблицу, выставляем для каждой записи цену (у одного поставщика может быть 30 различных цен по складам по всей России). Находим среднюю цену - выставляем для товара. Потом отдельная процедура конкатит все эти записи, и из 10 тысяч мы получаем 2-3 тысячи товаров в результирующей таблице, из которой потом и делаются выборки, по которой ведутся поиски.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать курсоры и любые циклы при работе с SQL надо в *очень редких*, особо тяжелых, случаях. Практически любую работу в SQL можно выполнить одним запросом. Ваш цикл по td_prices и вызов процедуры для обновления каждой отдельной строки можно заменить таким запросом:

```
UPDATE td_items I
  JOIN (SELECT item_id, sup_id,
               SUM(IF(buy_price > 0 AND amount > 0,buy_price*amount,0))
              /SUM(IF(buy_price > 0 AND amount > 0,amount,0)) as buy_price,
               SUM(amount) as amount
          FROM td_prices
         GROUP BY item_id, sup_id
       ) P
     ON I.in_id=P.item_id AND I.sup_id=P.sup_id
    SET I.buy_price=P.buy_price, I.amount=P.amount
```

`IF` пришлось применить т.к. у вас почему то используются немного разные выборки для количества (берущие вообще все записи) и цен (берущие большие нуля записи).
Вообще стоит подумать о дополнительных признаках по которым решать какие записи надо обновлять, а какие нет. Например вести поле timestamp в прайсах и менять только записи для которых в БД изменились какие либо цены с момента последнего обновления. Или вообще менять средние цены автоматом в триггере на изменение таблицы с прайсами.

Comment: Запрос отрабатывает в течение 10 секунд по всем 10 тысячам записей, вместо 10 минут через PHP. Благодарю за дельный совет!

Answer (score 3):

Подход, при котором ваш PHP-скрипт проходится по таблице и обновляет поле у каждой записи, конечно, очень медленный. 10 минут еще не так много. Когда ваша таблица станет больше, ждать придётся гораздо дольше.

А действительно ли вам нужно хранить поле со средней ценой? Если вы хотите получить список товаров со средними ценами можно использовать запрос:

```
select 
    g.id, 
    /* остальные необходимые поля*/, 
    SUM(p.buy_price*p.amount)/SUM(p.amount), SUM(p.amount)
from 
    td_goods g
    join td_prices p on p.item_id = g.id
group by 
    g.id, /* остальные необходимые поля*/
```

Можно на основе запроса сделать view и будет представление исходной таблицы, но с дополнительным полем содержащим усреднённую цену.

Comment: Все цены по всем записям хранятся в таблице. Вычислять среднюю цену необходимо, потому что представленные выше таблицы не являются окончательными. Так как данные в таблице td_items не уникальные (один и тот же товар может быть от разных поставщиков с разным sup_id и одинаковым in_id), другая большая процедура сливает их в одну конечную таблицу, сравнивая цены между одинаковыми записями (по артикулу, модели и бренду) и выставляет минимальную из средних цен, с указанием для какого поставщика эта цена действует.

Comment: У меня лишь один вопрос - как сделать переборку всех строк таблицы td_items в процедуре, исключая эту обработку в PHP. То есть сейчас я беру все записи из таблицы с помощью php, перебираю их и выставляю цену. Можно эту же процедуру выполнить прямо в SQL процедуре?

Comment: @AndrewKoshkin, а что вам мешает сливать в окончательную таблицу VIEW

Comment: @Mirdin, плохое знание SQL, потому что последние 5 лет я кроме ExtJS ничего не видел. Изучу данную тематику, спасибо.